# INVALID_STATE_ERR when calling CurrentTime before play video

Tags: html, video

I am using html5 video tag and using video.currentTime. In code, set the

```
video.currentTime = 0;
video.play()
```

Set the currentTime 0 before play the video as the video is in the loop. But in older version of chrome around 23, getting error like

```
Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

Tried some solution got on net like written CurrentTime in loadmetadata, canplay events

```
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata",function() { this.currentTime = 0;});
```

OR

```
video.addEventListener("canplay",function() { this.currentTime = 0;}
```

);

In such solution, an error has been gone but the video is not starting from 0.

Does anyone help me in this?

Comment: I normally check that `durationchange` has fired and that `duration > 0` before attempting to change `currentTime`

Comment: tried but it is not starting video with 0